# The most performant way to search a JS object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to match colors via common names or aliases of that color.

This is my current implementation, I'm breaking the object down into 16 separate arrays, then looping over each array to see if there is a match -

```
            if (colorMap) {
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(colorMap)) {
                    // colorMap broken down into arrays
                    let values = Object.values(value)
                    // If the color name is in the array
                    if (values[0].includes(swatch.color)) {
                        // add it to the swatch object
                        swatch.generic.push(key)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is colorMap -
[image]

But it is slow and doesn't always work, sometimes there can be hundreds of swatch.color so it times out.

Is there a more performant way to search this object?

Reference:

```
import { useMemo } from 'preact/hooks'

export const useSwatches = ({
    variantColors,
    colorMap,
    variantImages,
    swatchImages,
    fallbackImage,
}) => {
    return useMemo(() => {
        if (!variantColors || !swatchImages || !variantImages) {
            return []
        } else {
            let swatchList = new Set();
            let swatches = JSON.parse(swatchImages)
            let images = JSON.parse(variantImages)
            let colorMap = JSON.parse(window.Resources.colorMap.textContent)
               

            variantColors.forEach(function (color, index) {
                let swatch = new Object();

                swatch.color = color.replaceAll('  ', ' ');

                swatch.generic = []

                swatch.fallback_img = fallbackImage;

                images.forEach(function (img, index) {
                    if (img.color == swatch.color) {
                        swatch.thumbnail = img.img;
                    }
                })

                if (!swatch.thumbnail) {
                    swatch.thumbnail = fallbackImage
                }

                swatches.forEach(function (img, index) {
                    let splitImg = img.split('/');
                    let swatchMatcher = splitImg[splitImg.length-1];

                    if (swatchMatcher.split('.')[0] === (swatch.color.replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase())) {
                        swatch.swatch_image = img
                    }
                })

                if (!swatch.swatch_image) {
                    swatch.swatch_image = fallbackImage
                }

                if (colorMap) {    
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(colorMap)) {
                        // colorMap broken down into arrays
                        let values = Object.values(value)
                        // If the color name is in the array
                        if (values[0].includes(swatch.color)) {
                            // add it to the swatch object
                            swatch.generic.push(key)
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                swatchList.add(swatch);
            });

            return swatchList;
        }
    }, [
        variantColors,
        colorMap,
        variantImages,
        swatchImages,
        fallbackImage,
    ])
}
```

Comment: Don't use an object of arrays that you have to search through. Use a `Map` where you can directly look up the result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays, you can use an ES6 set (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which can perform search queries in logarithmic time instead of linear time.

In your case, you can make each property of the `colorMap` variable a set instead of an array, and then call `values[0].has(swatch.color)` instead of `values[0].includes(swatch.color)`

But, the most performant way would be to precompute a bookkeeping array that maps each color alias to the color it references and then simply look it up in O(1) time.